# A way to solder composite video directly to RPi B+ board?

Tags: gpio, hardware, audio, video, composite-video

I have a b+ newly purchased that I'm slimming down for a handheld build.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to solder my composite video connection to the underside of the board like I could with a model B.  However, I can't find any diagrams for how the TRRS connector pins are mapped to location on the board.

If at all possible, I'd love to keep the actual connector open for a MTF plug to allow headphone input – short of that, being able to solder in the video and ground leads would be terrific. Not opposed to using the GPIO if that's possible either.

Trying to hook up an AFUNTA 4.3" display to a Raspberry Pi B+ *without* using the TRRS jack directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the diagram I found:
[image]

In case if the image will be moved, you count pins on male 3.5"mm connectors starting from tip:

1. Left Audio (PP25 on the RPi)
2. Right Audio (PP26 on the RPi)
3. Ground
4. Video (PP24 on the RPi)

The video appears as marked **PP24** on the back of the board. It's the middle pin of 3.

The Ground can be used from many other places. I think PP3 and PP6 are the easiest for this case.

Comment: I've seen this diagram, but tracing ring 4 to the motherboard isn't immediately apparent.  Hard to get a multimeter pin in there and even harder to gauge if I'm hitting the correct contact.  Any other information you might have on this would be more useful.

Comment: I updated my response. It's marked as PP24 on the back of the board.

Comment: Awesome!  If you could tell me which is the ground, I'll mark your answer as accepted and award the bounty.

Comment: Ground is everywhere, this is just ground. Any ground on the board is good for you. For example, take the next unmarked pin (all 3.5"mm jack connector's pins are marked except ground). I'll update my original response with other pins. I think PP3 is the simplest to take for the ground.

Comment: – I appreciate it.  Still new to the hardware side of all this.

Comment: PP6 is another choice for the Ground. I think it's even better, depending on your soldering skills. Just don't overheat it too much (at most 2 seconds holding it, following by about 4-5 seconds cooling it).